# Can we get the skype user id using the skype handle

Tags: skype, botframework

How can we get the user id ( something like 1hRVUAus5JxCuZfhxPOjmKCtoZoO22ps0FBGKiM) of a skype contact using the skype username/handle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Username of skype from Microsoft Bot Framework Channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503468/find-username-of-skype-from-microsoft-bot-framework-channel)

Answer (score 1):

yes, **Jyothis Jose** you can get userId and userName using following code in c#

```
if(activity.From.Name != null)
{
string userName= activity.From.Name;
string userID=activity.From.Id;
 //Perform your action
}
```