# How to get email of user in Skype bot

Tags: botframework, skype

I am wanting to be able to post messages to Skype users via my bot, ideally the message would be posted using the users email address however the channel account for the user only has Id and Name.

Why does Skype not provide this information on the Activity?

Comment: Because it's personal information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Username of skype from Microsoft Bot Framework Channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503468/find-username-of-skype-from-microsoft-bot-framework-channel)

Comment: You don't need the email address to post a message to the users. You just need the details of the channel account.

Comment: I understand that i can post to a channel account but in my use case i have a seperate system that wants to post notifications to skype users, in this instance it would seem logical that it posts to the user who registers on that system with their email address. Without this ability it seems you would need to be able to lookup a Skype user in the directory to get the channel information