# No ChannelData except message text while receiving incoming message from Skype in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, bots, skype

When I'm receiving the message from Telegram, I get detailed information about account in Activity.ChannelData field (such as username, conversation_id and so on).

```
{
  "update_id": ,
  "callback_query": {
    "id": "",
    "from": {
      "id": ,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": "",
      "username": "",
      "language_code": ""
    },
    "message": {
      "message_id": ,
      "from": {
        "id": ,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "",
        "username": ""
      },
      "chat": {
        "id": ,
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "username": "",
        "type": "private"
      },
      "date": ,
      "text": "Example text"
    },
    "chat_instance": "",
    "data": ""
  }
}
```

But when it comes to Skype, all I see is the message text and nothing else.

```
{  "text": "Example text"}
```

How to know out, who exatly sent me the message?

**Upd:** That should not be exactly the user's name, any additional data like user unique id would fit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Username of skype from Microsoft Bot Framework Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503468/find-username-of-skype-from-microsoft-bot-framework-channel)

Comment: you do not need to pull this data from channel data, the activity object will have the user's id in the `activity.from.id` or `activity.recepient.id` field depending on which direction the message is going.  Every channel's channel data is different.

Comment: @JasonSowers thank you so much. I should've explored activity object more carefully.

Comment: @StevenKanberg D4RKCIDE gave the right answer above. You can clear your answer from your support tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what is returned is channel specific, as determined by the channel developers. It is not a function of the Azure Bot Service or Bot Framework that determines this.

As for knowing who sent a message, this is not possible. Skype only returns a unique id per user in order to provide a layer of confidentiality with respect to privacy concerns.

Comment: The problem is that I don't even get a unique id. Only message text.