# How to get the Skype username using skype calling feature

Tags: bots, skype, botframework, botconnector

I am working on Bot Technology, in my current bot project I implemented the skype calling feature using calling controller. everything working fine, but I have struggled for getting the skype username (like who are logged into skype) in **CallingController.cs** or some other classes.

In **MessagesController.cs** , I know for getting the skype username by using this line.

```
var username = activity.From.Name.ToString();
```

Can you please tell me how to get the skype username using skype calling feature not in MessagesController.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be able to get the identity of the user by checking the [Participants](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling/Models/Contracts/Conversation.cs#L24) collection of the `Conversation` object, right after the [incoming call](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling/CallingBotService.cs#L102) is received.

You can read more of the Skype Calling API [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/calling/#calling-conversation-object-model).

Comment: Thanks @Jadib, I wrote the below line of code for getting the identity but I don't want this one , I want the username instead of identity.

var userName= incomingCallEvent.IncomingCall.Participants.Select(x => x.Identity).FirstOrDefault();

when I write the below line I got the null value.

var userName= incomingCallEvent.IncomingCall.Participants.Select(x => x.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();

can you please tell me how can I get username instead of identity.

Comment: The username per se is not provided by Skype. So you might be getting the same unique Id that Skype is returning when using the standard bot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377169/can-we-get-the-skype-user-id-using-the-skype-handle